# Can't find this kanji

Tags: kanji

Normally, I don't have much trouble finding written kanji. However, this one has me stumped:

[image]

The closest character I can find is 逃.

Comment: It's the same character, in old style.

Comment: Nice question, I learnt both an nice new kanji and verb today!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the same character, but the image you showed gives in its traditional form, and an old style. 逃 in previous forms has 2 dots in its radical 辶, as with many other characters.

Also, the writing style is slightly old, so it looks different in "font" if you will to the computer graphics version of the character.

Looks like you didn't have much trouble finding this kanji either!

Comment: btw I think this kind of font is used to produce a creepy atmosphere rather than archaic (especially in manga).

Comment: @broccoliforest, I'd say it could arguably be both in style (the fact that it looks old building to the feeling of creepiness). But, considering the meaning of the character, I'd be willing to bet that creepiness is definitely a bigger aspect ; )